# how to use angular's ng-repeat filter with input outside the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the angular's ng-repeat filter like so:

```
 <div ng-repeat="trade in trades | filter:searchTrades | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

the problem here is the input control where I want to bind "searchTrades" to exists OUTSIDE the controller and view where the ng-repeate exists.  the input field exists outside the controller for a good reason.  it's a global search input that i intend to use **differently with each controller**.  so further more I will need to give the search input different behavior depending on which controller/view is active.

Comment: Is the scope `searchTrades` an ancestor scope of the scope where you use ngRepeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of scopes, and eventing between scopes. As angular uses prototype inheritance, you can still gain access to "parent" scope properties and react to them.

The short of it, if you have `searchTrades` on a parent controller, the child controller can access it. *Note* if the child controller modifies `searchTrades` it will make a "new copy", if you need to do that use `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$on`

**[Here is a plunker to look at](http://plnkr.co/edit/alugT2YfT3t6OvH7xyCV?p=preview)**

Consider the following

**Controllers**

```
function MainCtrl($scope, ...) {
    $scope.search = 'My search term' 
}

function ChildCtrl1($scope, ...) {
    $scope.items = ['Foo', ... ]
}
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label>Search</label> <input ng-model="search" />

    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl1">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

ChildCtrl1 will inherit `search` from the parent controller, and it can be used as "normal"

Comment: wonderful.  was as simple as adding a parent controller.  is this a good pattern to just add an all encompassing main controller for these types of situations?  can't think of another reason why i would need this parent controller (for now).  thanks again.

Comment: You will need a controller to bind to your <input /> in this case. If you wanted to do this without a controller, you could, with event subscription on the input, and likely and angular service. But it's just more work. If you think about it from a data perspective your search input *is* part of your model, thus needs a controller.